# Can't pickle PyCapsule in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wrote a c library for python as .so object that I import. Inside, I use PyCapsules to manipulate C structures or use C functions and it works well. I want to parrallelize the usage of the function in my .so lib using the multiprocessing.Pool. It's seems that multiprocessing.Pool can't pickle PyCapsules:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'PyCapsule'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.PyCapsule failed
```

Does anybody have an idea if there is a workaround?
Thanks.